# Show "rejoin all rooms" button unless explicitly declined

Tags: feature-request, chat, favorite-rooms

Self-explanatory, sometimes I open my browser and have like two tabs open, and since I'm in more than one room the rejoin button doesn't show up.

Please show this button always, so that I can join all my favorite rooms even in such case.

Comment: I'd like this - currently my workaround to get my 30-odd chat rooms open takes multiple clicks to get to all rooms, rejoin all

Comment: @RoryAlsop yeah, that's what I currently do too

Comment: @Rory no button [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=favorite)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's the button he's talking about

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Also :| why did you remove the part about mobile

Comment: Thought the button always appear in the favorite tab, just not in the rooms. As for removing the part, it should be a separate feature request. We can't have two feature requests in one question.

Comment: Well, I do see "rejoin all" button in favorite tab of chat always. If you don't see it there, it's a bug. The only button which gets hidden when you're in more than one room is the one inside each room. /cc @Rory

Comment: that's the problem Sha Wiz. If you are in just one chat it's fine, but if you have a couple open, that option vanishes from the room options. Which is what the feature request is.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, not the favorites, that takes a lot of effort - usually the button is visible in the sidebar

Comment: As someone with a lot of tabs open all the time (especially now that I'm a CM at the company), this is definitely something I experience semi-often. Especially if I have two chat tabs open in different windows...